# Can SMTP used as Incoming Protocol in Exchange server

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

So i want to know whether an organisation can use or not SMTP protocol for Receiving Emails from Exchange server. As i read, The Standard for Receiving are `POP3` or `IMAP`, and the `SMTP` Protocol is standard for Sending.
My Question is just whether it is possible to use `SMTP` as Incoming Protocol .
If Yes, Then i want to know how will i read its messages using JavaMail API.

I am trying the following code. but getting `NoSuchProviderException`

```
 private void fetch(String incomingHost, String username, String password) {
    try {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", incomingHost);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 25);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", false);

        emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties);

        Store store = emailSession.getStore();

        store.connect(incomingHost, 25, username, password);

        // create the folder object and open it
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("---------------------------------" + message.getDescription());
            //writePart(message);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if ("YES".equals(line)) {
                message.writeTo(System.out);
            } else if ("QUIT".equals(line)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // close the store and folder objects
        emailFolder.close(false);
        store.close();

    } catch (javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "no", but stackoverflow requires me to add all these words to make the answer long enough.

Comment: i have a doubt. can we fetch emails from MS Exchange server via JavaMail API. if yes then how? what exactly the server details will be needed to fetch mails from MS exchange

Comment: You need to enable IMAP support in Exchange.  Then you can use JavaMail to fetch mail from Exchange just like any other IMAP server.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) to get started.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shannon